# driver is getting null for utility classes

Tags: selenium-webdriver, browser-automation, test-automation-framework

I'm getting null pointer exception for `driver` object.

Here is the flow:

1. `BaseClass` initializes the `driver` (`WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();`)
2. I create a test class and extend it with BaseClass. Now I am able to use all methods present in BaseClass example `navigate`, `openBrowser`, `click` , `type`, `isLogin` etc
3. Then I create a utility class.
4. There is if I am using `navigate` it is giving me null pointer exception though `util` class also extends `BaseClass`, because `Util` also uses methods present in `BaseClass`.

**Flow is for Test Class is:**

```
openBrowser("Chrome"); // driver present
method from BaseClass;driver present
method from BaseClass;driver present
method from BaseClass;driver present
method from util class;driver=null
```

What am I doing wrong?

**Edit:**
I checked Thiago Fioravante's answer here [WebDriver instantiation in Selenium framework](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/25122/webdriver-instantiation-in-selenium-framework) but didn't quite get it, what he is saying. However, problem same i.e. I want to use same driver instance across the project.

**Edit2:**
This navigate method is working in test Classes but not in Util Classes. It is giving driver = null

```
public void navigate(String url) {
        driver.get(url);
        logger("Navigating to " + url);
    }
```

Comment: Can you paste minimal representative code snippet? Of those your three classes. It it pretty hard to imaging the real picture from your description.

Comment: @AlexeyR. I want to use same driver instance that I instantiated in BaseClass across the project. All my classes util classes, test classes have to extend BaseClass to use generic methods over there.

Answer (score 0):

With the little understanding I am replying to this question. As far as I understood  `UtilClass` extends `BaseClass` and also `Test Class` extends `BaseClass`. But there is no where a `UtilClass` is extending your `TestClass`. Try creating an instance of the `UtilClass` in `TestClass` something like below in your code.

```
UtilClass uc = new UtilClass();
uc.requiredMethod();
```

Comment: UtilClass is one, test classes are so many. How I will make it work for all test classes?

Comment: I guess then you have to make a choice of extending either one of Base or Util in each Test Class depending upon the what method calls your going to make.

Comment: Do you mind checking the code via Team Viewer?

Comment: I would love to do that after a while as I have limited internet access as of now. You can even convert your `BaseClass` into an interface. Where you can implement `BaseClass` and extend `UtilClass` in your `TestClass` at same time. [Click here for reference.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24378375/java-if-a-extends-b-and-b-extends-object-is-that-multiple-inheritance)

Comment: Ok let me try, but give me a time slot so that we can connect at that time. It's 5.15pm here in Delhi, India.

Comment: That's great I work in the same timezone too. Let's catch up at anywhere in between 7-8PM.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/73472/discussion-between-bradz-and-paul).

Answer (score 0):

I have a different idea on creating the Utility methods. They should be common to all all classes in the architecture. So you can achieve this by making the methods inside the util class as public static. Then you can just call the method by class name.